# How do I merge SMS threads?

Tags: sms

I sent an SMS to several contacts, so Android put it in one thread as "Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dylan, Ed, and 5 more". Then Bob and Ed replied, each having their own threads.

Can I merge Bob's and Ed's threads with the multi-contact thread? How do I do that?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: @Matthew, it's a Samsung Galaxy S Advanced that came with 2.3.6. I think it should be similar to the S, R, and S2.

Answer (score 1):

From http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1227352 :

> I successfully merged SMS threads by creating a backup using SMS Backup & Restore.
>
> Just open the created .xml file in e.g. Notepad++, then replace your
>   contact's old number in the "address" field with the new one. Now load
>   the altered backup file back onto your phone, delete your messages
>   from within the app, and restore your newly created backup file.
>   Although it worked fine for me on the first try, I recommend keeping
>   your initial backup file, and save your editing to a copy - just in
>   case.
>
> Using this method, I also fixed some splitted threads, where one
>   contact with one number got split up in several threads, because of an
>   incorrect number restore from backups when switching phones.
>
> Hope this helps. :)

Here's [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible in the current Messages app for any of the Android releases.

Maybe you can consider third party SMS apps which handle multi-messages different.